# Format XML and return to the same line in Vim

Tags: vim

I would like to map <kbd>F5</kbd> to format the current buffer using `xmllint --format` and return to the same line.  It's easy to do just the formatting.

```
autocmd FileType xml map <F5> :w<CR>:silent %!xmllint --format -<CR>
```

I played around with returning to the same line for a while, and from the below snipped it should be obvious I don't know what I'm doing (doesn't work at all).

```
fun! XmlFormat()
  let @`\" = line(".")
  w<CR>
  silent %!xmllint --format -<CR>
  normal! g`\"
endfun
autocmd FileType xml map <F5> :call XmlFormat()<CR>
```

Do I need to store the present line in a buffer, or can I use a variable?  How can I execute an external command within a function?  Lastly, what's the best way to jump to a line number that is stored in a variable?

Comment: Rather than using xmllint, which squeezes blank newlines, I would suggest trying the [vim-sensible](https://github.com/tpope/vim-sensible) settings, which make equals (=) work out of the box to indent XML. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/28365920/1207769

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a mapping like:

```
nnoremap <f5> mmgg=G`m
```

It uses a [mark](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#mark) motion and the [=](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#=) filter command. You could use xmllint setting the [equalprg](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27equalprg%27) option. I wrote an article about this mapping [here](http://lucapette.com/vim/rails/vim-for-rails-developers-indenting-code/) if you want a more detailed description.

Comment: You don't need `map` here, you need `nnoremap`.

Comment: One can take advantage of the fact that Vim automatically saves the position before the latest jump, to simplify the command and avoid modification of marks: `:nnoremap <f5> gg=G\`\``.

Comment: @ib oh yes. I love vim for that. I learn at least one thing a day