# Vim indent xml file

Tags: xml, vim

I am learning Vim but I thought this was a simple task but I cannot get it to work. I have browser SO but the solutions are not working for me.

I am trying to correctly indent an file (xml). The command I use is:

```
gg=G
```

or
    ggVG= (made this one up myself probably does something different ;))

My .vimrc is:

```
syntax on 
filetype plugin indent on 
set nu
```

Comment: What's the original, result, and expected output?

Comment: What's the output of `:set ft? indentexpr?` Does it read `filetype=xml indentexpr=XmlIndentGet(v:lnum,1)`?!

Comment: filetype=xml   indentexpr=XmlIndentGet(v:lnum,1). Yup

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11655383/vim-formatting-using-gg-g-with-xml#11660992

Comment: I like to add just a little to this map and make it `m'ggVG=''`, which simply saves the line you're on and moves back to it after reindenting the file.

Comment: Note to self: `:% !xmllint "%" --format` (input: content of current file; output: written to current file; [from Vim Tips Wiki](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Format_your_xml_document_using_xmllint#xmllint_on_Windows))

Comment: No one mentioned the excellent [Format your XML document using `xmllint`](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Format_your_xml_document_using_xmllint) article that has a ton of examples, but also alternatives to `xmllint`.

Answer (score 246, accepted):

I like Berei's answer. However, I think the following is a little more flexible in that you don't have to alter your `vimrc` file. Plus it is easier to format select portions of the XML file (something I happen to do a lot).

First, highlight the XML you want to format.

Then, in visual mode, type `! xmllint --format -`

Your command-line at the bottom will look like this:

`:'<,'>!xmllint --format -`

Then hit enter.

### Technical Explanation

The selected text is sent to the `xmllint` command, then `--format`'ed, and the results of `xmllint` are placed over your selected text in vim. The `-` at the end of the command is for receiving standard input - which, in this case, is the selected text that vim sends to `xmllint`.

Comment: This of course only works if you have the external tool xmllint installed and added to your path.

Comment: to simplify the command, `:%!xmllint --format -`, `%` means the whole scope of this xml file.

Comment: Why does everybody expect there is an xmllint tool? In Ubuntu 15.04 there isn't and apt-get also can't find one.

Comment: @erikb85 Use `apt-cache search`, not `apt-get`, when searching for packages and package contents. `libxml2-utils` contains the missing tool.

Comment: @hakunami i wish i could upvote you 1000 times for simplifying that process

Comment: I added this to my .vimrc to map the leader key followed by 'X' to format an entire document:
`nmap <leader>X ggVG !xmllint --format -<CR>`

Comment: if you want to add syntax highligt, then use highlight like this :  `:'<,'>!xmllint --format - | highlight --out-format=ansi --syntax=xml`

if you do not have highlight, then install it like this : `sudo apt install -yq highlight`

Comment: Why not use standard vim way of formatting? With smartindent and filetype it works without external dependency.

Comment: What I don't like about this approach is that it inserts <?xml version="1.0"?>

Comment: I found this link : https://gist.github.com/jlacar/00a07453ec4344cf0194 
used this commande :       :%!xmllint "%" --format

Comment: Now tidy (http://api.html-tidy.org/) is able to format better xml files, with the possibility of config files. Similarly also prittier (https://prettier.io/) provides a plugin to format xml. Personally I find then better than xmllint. This may be interesting for ROS developers.

Answer (score 81):

Use an external program to indent your `xml` files. In this case I've choosen `xmllint`, so set the command to the `equalprg` option:

```
:set equalprg=xmllint\ --format\ -
```

Now you can execute

```
gg=G
```

to let `xmllint` format your `xml` files.

To get it every time you use [vim](/questions/tagged/vim), use an `autocommand` to set it.

`autocommand` from a comment below

```
au FileType xml setlocal equalprg=xmllint\ --format\ --recover\ -\ 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: Not sure why this works hence the beginner but I will figure this one out ;) Thank you it works nows ;)

Comment: You can use the following in your .vimrc to enable it when editing xml files - ```au FileType xml setlocal equalprg=xmllint\ --format\ --recover\ -\ 2>/dev/null```. Source - http://ku1ik.com/2011/09/08/formatting-xml-in-vim-with-indent-command.html

Comment: Thank you! Very frustrated with large XML files and vim, in Sublime they reindents very quickly (5000-10000 lines and base64 data), but in Vim they reindents several minutes. This solution fix problem with large XML files. Again I happy with Vim.

Comment: if you are on ubuntu, you'll need to install the `libxml2-utils` package to get xmllint

Answer (score 39):

A simple solution that I like which doesn't require any 3rd party tool is to insert a newline before each opening tag '<...>'. Then you can use standard vim auto-indentation. In short:

1. `%s/</\r</g`
2. `gg=G` to auto indent

Comment: I've tried it with a big xml file and it's verrrrry long to process.

Comment: Thank you. This is easy enough and does the job without requiring external tools.

Comment: I prefer `%s/></>\r</g`, so that each text element remains on the same line.

Comment: @NicolaMusatti Or if there are sometimes spaces between tags, `%s/> *</>\r</g`

Comment: It replies "115 lines indented" but nothing is indented. What options does this require to be set? Or does this method actually require external dependencies I don't have?

Comment: krubo maybe your filetype isn’t correctly set.

Answer (score 13):

**Short answer:** Turn on [matchit.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=39). You can add `packadd matchit` to your `.vimrc`, or use [vim-sensible](https://github.com/tpope/vim-sensible), which enables it by default.

**Long answer:** I have tried many strategies to auto-indent XML in Vim, including the [xmllint approach discussed on the Vim wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Format_your_xml_document_using_xmllint). The problem with `xmllint` (and the same approach with other external CLI tools such as `xmlformat` and `tidy`, too) is that they all insist on squeezing out blank newlines. If all you want is to indent your XML, without removing blank lines, comments and/or other intentional formatting, then `xmllint` is not the best choice.

It turns out that Vim's equals (=) command already supports XML, as long as the [matchit.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=39) script is enabled. One super easy way to enable it is to adopt tpope's [vim-sensible](https://github.com/tpope/vim-sensible). Another is to add `packadd matchit` to your `.vimrc`. Then, XML formatting will "just work" out of the box.

Comment: To be more precise, it looks like `matchit.vim` is the actual solution. You can enable it in your `vimrc` by adding this line: `packadd matchit`

Comment: Thanks Christian; I updated the answer to clarify that matchit.vim is what solves the problem.

Comment: Upvoted because this worked best for me. However, I would suggest adding Christian's suggestion (packadd matchit) to the short answer as it is very simple and does the job (at least for me)

Comment: @mark I updated the answer to include Christian's suggestion.

Comment: Hmm - so, what's the exact command to format an existing xml file without any line breaks using this approach? I've tried `gg=G` which did nothing. To be precise: i don't want to indent a single line correctly, i want to pretty-print the entire XML file (btw: the xmllint command did the trick, but i want to understand why the matchit.vim approach or vim-sensible didn't work). Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: @tohuwawohu Use the `=` command. If you are at the top of the file, you can type `=G`. Alternately, you can go to the top of the file with `1G`, enter visual line select mode with `V`, then type `G` to go to the bottom of the file, selecting everything. And then press `=` to indent the whole file. Similarly, if you only want to indent part of a file, select only that part, and press `=`.

Comment: @tohuwawohu I just realized you said "without any line breaks". The `=` command won't insert (or remove) line breaks that aren't already present. It only affects leading indentation. So `matchit.vim` is not a solution for pretty-printing XML that's all squished onto one line. Use `xmllint` or similar for that.

Answer (score 11):

This is easy to achieve once ~/.vimrc is setup properly.

Set the following options in ~/.vimrc:

```
filetype indent on
set smartindent
```

This allows you to move the cursor to the top of the file and indent to the end: gg=G

You can also select the desired text with visual mode and hit = to indent it.

Comment: I suppose it will be `.vimrc` instead of `.bashrc`.

Comment: Whoops. Exactly. Fixed that. Thank you.

Comment: That would work when every tag is in a line. If the XML doesn't have spaces nor end lines, this would do not do anything at all.

Comment: It has always worked for me as long as the markup is valid.

Comment: If your markup is not (consitently?) on distinct lines you can sloppily change that with :%s/</\r</g and then :%s/\n\n/\r/

Comment: If you want your HTML to pretty print you can use this script I made a while back: https://github.com/jarederaj/CleanHTML

Answer (score 9):

Jesse Hogan's answer is good, but I'd rather more simple answer:

While you are in vim and your XML file is opened, in normal mode write this:

```
:%!xmllint --format %
```

then press Enter. All of your XML file will be formatted.

remember you should have installed *xmllint* before.

Answer (score 6):

In VIM, I auto-indent the whole file (using hard tabs) using the following command:

```
:%!XMLLINT_INDENT="^I" xmllint --format -
```

The `^I` is a single character you generate via: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>,<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. It turned out, that the line

```
set viewdir=~\.vim\views\
```

in my `.vimrc` caused the problem. Just make sure, you don't have it.

Answer (score 0):

for those one which is using `coc.nvim` plugin, you can install `coc-xml` by `:CocInstall coc-xml` 
, then mapping format key in your config file: `nmap <silent> fm <Plug>(coc-format)`. From now on, you can format not only xml file but other file very easy

Answer (score 0):

Cannot get `coc-xml` working due to some java issue. Turns out using python's xml module could be a quick solution given many modern systems already come with python. Add below to your `.vimrc`

> com! FormatXML :%!python3 -c "import xml.dom.minidom, sys; print(xml.dom.minidom.parse(sys.stdin).toprettyxml())"

Now you can do `:FormatXML` from *command* mode. Then set syntax highlight with

```
:set ft=xml
# OR
:set syntax=xml
```

---

**Bonus**: since I was doing this with SAML you can quickly decode *base64* inside vim/neovim by selecting the base64 text(visual mode) and do `!base64 -d` in command mode. it will show as below in command:

> :'<,'>!base64 -d