# python: retaining xml formatting using etree

Tags: python, xml

I'm using lxml etree to format xml and modify some values. Here's a snippet of the input XML

```
        <FIELD
            NAME="A"
            SHORT_DESCRIPTION="AAAAA"
            OFFSET="0"
            WIDTH="0"
        >       </FIELD>

        <FIELD
            NAME="B"
            SHORT_DESCRIPTION="BBBBBB"
            OFFSET="1"
            WIDTH="1"
        >       </FIELD>
```

code:

```
        from lxml import etree as ET
        tree = ET.parse(path)
        root = tree.getroot()
        #read and modify attributes
        tree.write('output.xml', pretty_print=True)
```

But the output is of the form:

```
 <FIELD NAME="A" SHORT_DESCRIPTION="AAAAA" OFFSET="100" WIDTH="0"> </FIELD>
```

I tried converting it into a string and then using etree but I get the same results.

I expect it to be in the same format as the XML was originally with the attributes across several lines.

Comment: How are you opening the XML? If you open the file using VScode or another editor as an XML it will format it in the way that you want

Comment: I'm using vim; but the issue is that others would want the XML to be open in human readable form using emacs or vi.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vim indent xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21408222/vim-indent-xml-file)

Comment: It's more of vim doing its job before I run my script and the script merges all attributes to a single line.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of reading, modifying & writing and XML file using `lxml`:

**PS:** Your XML input is not valid, you need to wrap it in a parend tag

**input.xml**

```
<items>
<FIELD NAME="A" SHORT_DESCRIPTION="AAAAA" OFFSET="0" WIDTH="0"></FIELD>
<FIELD NAME="B" SHORT_DESCRIPTION="BBBBBB" OFFSET="1" WIDTH="1"></FIELD>
</items>
```

**modify_xml.py**

```
from lxml import etree as ET


tree = ET.parse('input.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
# find all fields in the given root
fields = root.iterfind('.//FIELD')
# Example of modifying text and attributes of fields
for field in fields:
    if field.get('OFFSET') == '0':
        field.set('SHORT_DESCRIPTION', 'aaaa')
        field.text = 'TEST 0'
    else:
        field.set('SHORT_DESCRIPTION', 'bbbb')
        field.text = 'TEST 1'

tree.write('output.xml')
```

**output.xml**

```
<items>
<FIELD NAME="A" SHORT_DESCRIPTION="aaaa" OFFSET="0" WIDTH="0">TEST 0</FIELD>
<FIELD NAME="B" SHORT_DESCRIPTION="bbbb" OFFSET="1" WIDTH="1">TEST 1</FIELD>
</items>
```